# Build Mysql query with forearch loop php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Values are inside a multidimenssional array like:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array (
        [fname] => CollectiveAccess
        [lname] => Administrator
        [username] => administrator
        )
    [1] => Array (
        [fname] => Jorge
        [lname] => Ghelman 
        [username] => jorgeghe 
        )
    [2] => Array (
        [fname] => Sebastian
        [lname] => Scarano
        [username] => sscarano
        )
)
```

This is the loop I use to build the query:

```
foreach ($user_names as $value) {
    foreach ($value as  $value2) {
        echo $value2 . " "; //prints all values
        $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, fname, lname)
                  VALUES ('$value2', );";
    }
}
```

print_r($query) shows that only the last value from $value2 is passed to the query.

```
INSERT INTO users (username, fname, lname) VALUES ('test1', );
```

I'm sure it's a rookie mistake but can't figure it out.
Thanks

Comment: Concatenate values into query string.

Comment: Surely you're using [parametrized queries](http://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/502381) so this won't be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
foreach ($user_names as $value) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO users (username, fname, lname)
              VALUES ('{$value['username']}', '{$value['fname']}', '{$value['lname']}');";
    echo $query;
}
```

Comment: It worked like a charm! Thanks!. I have some php book but none of them contains situations like this one, it's frustrating. Thanks again.